# How to execute MYSQL query in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have one MYSQL query with me I want to execute this query in laravel.

```
    select d1.update_id from ( select update_id, count(update_id)
 as ct from updates_tags where tag_id in 
(67,33,86,55) group by update_id) as d1 where d1.ct=4
```

Please guide me how do i Do it easily.

I have one reference with me.... It is not working

```
    $updateArray = DB::table('updates_tags')
->select('update_id', DB::raw('count(*) as update_id'))
->whereIn('tag_id',$jsontags)
->groupBy('update_id')
->having('update_id','=',count($jsontags))
->lists('update_id');
```

Comment: please, precise what is not working, is there an error ? if yes what error, if no, what do you get as result ?

Comment: @n00dl3 : I am not able to arrange the query in the laravel format and it gives me the SQL query violation error While I am executing.

Comment: Did you tried to execute the single query in MySQL, without PHP/Laravel? I'm not sure, but... what if there is an error in your query?

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-web-apps-from-scratch-with-laravel-the-eloquent-orm--net-25631

Comment: JuanjoSalvador:  it is working fine with MySQL and it gives me output what i want. but not able to convert it in laravel.

Answer (score 4):

You can just do a RAW query.
like this:

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT d1.update_id FROM...";
$result = DB::select(DB::raw($sqlQuery));
```

the $result will be an array

Comment: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Giving this error.

Comment: where are you doing it? in the controller? try to print it' see what you get. use var_dump($result) or print_r($result)

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [update_id] => 2
        )

)
{"code":"","message":"","results":[]}

Comment: Array
(
    [2] => 2
)
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#651 (1) {
    ["update_id"]=>
    int(2)
  }
}

Comment: so your query is incorrect, there is nothing to do with Laravel itself.
show us the structure of your data then we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

change the `where('total','=',count($tags)) to having('total','=',count($tags))`

```
$update = DB::table('tags')
->select('t_id', 'u_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
->whereIn('t_id',$tags)
->groupBy('u_id')
->having('total','=',count($tags))
->lists('u_id');
```

Comment: I am beginner in the laravel. Is it working same as MYSQL query. ?

select d1.update_id from ( select update_id, count(update_id)
 as ct from updates_tags where tag_id in 
(67,33,86,55) group by update_id) as d1 where d1.ct=4

Comment: the update_id has been used already so you cannot use it as your alias. Thats what you are using as the first select. So give it another name

Comment: Yes I am getting the right value from above laravel query it is return the update_id.  

$updateArray  = UpdatesTags::whereIn('tag_id',$jsontags)->lists('update_id');

This is returning array but our query is not.

Comment: if you want it to return array add ->all() to the query. like this ->lists('u_id')->all();

Comment: Call to a member function all() on a non-object

Comment: Just checked i think it because you are using Query Builder. What do you get without the ->all()

Answer (score 0):

In classic PHP, we used to use `mysqli` connector. In CodeIgniter, we use ActiveRecords (fully lovely). In Laravel, there is also ActiveRecords for SQL queries.

Checkout the official Laravel docs, query builder is your friend. https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries

Comment: I tried with official Laravel docs .. Not succeed that's y i come here for help.

Comment: Check your query, it may be a SQL mistake.

Comment: select d1.update_id from ( select update_id, count(update_id)
 as ct from updates_tags where tag_id in 
(67,33,86,55) group by update_id) as d1 where d1.ct=4

This MYSQL query gives me output what i want.. Which is true.