# Laravel DB::select not return value as expected

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm having problem to view data using db::select.

Here is my full sql statement [Tested and return value as expected on mysql]

```
SELECT tugasan_kontrak.*,sejarah.tkh_wujud AS tkh_wujud ,sejarah.id_tindakan AS id_tindakan 
FROM tugasan_kontrak 
LEFT JOIN sejarah ON(
tugasan_kontrak.id_tugasan = sejarah.id_tugasan AND 
jenis_tugasan='k' AND 
sejarah.id_tindakan !='99' AND
id_sejarah = (SELECT MAX(id_sejarah) FROM sejarah WHERE 
    tugasan_kontrak.id_tugasan = sejarah.id_tugasan AND jenis_tugasan='k') 
)
WHERE pegawai_tugas='890911105098' AND id_tindakan IS NOT NULL
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1Nmk.png)

But when I try to apply this statement using `db::select`, no record were view.

Here the function I use to test

```
public function getPenggunaTindakan($value='890911105098')
{
    $kontrak = DB::select("select tugasan_kontrak.*,sejarah.tkh_wujud as tkh_wujud ,sejarah.id_tindakan as id_tindakan 
            from tugasan_kontrak left join sejarah on(tugasan_kontrak.id_tugasan = sejarah.id_tugasan and jenis_tugasan='k' and sejarah.id_tindakan !='99' and
                id_sejarah = (select max(id_sejarah) from sejarah where tugasan_kontrak.id_tugasan = sejarah.id_tugasan and jenis_tugasan='k'))
        where pegawai_tugas=:nokp and id_tindakan is not null ",['nokp' => $value]);

    dd($kontrak);
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Maybe this will  help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36331289/how-to-execute-mysql-query-in-laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following :

```
DB::select(DB::raw("select tugasan_kontrak.*,sejarah.tkh_wujud as tkh_wujud ,sejarah.id_tindakan as id_tindakan 
            from tugasan_kontrak left join sejarah on(tugasan_kontrak.id_tugasan = sejarah.id_tugasan and jenis_tugasan='k' and sejarah.id_tindakan !='99' and
                id_sejarah = (select max(id_sejarah) from sejarah where tugasan_kontrak.id_tugasan = sejarah.id_tugasan and jenis_tugasan='k'))
        where pegawai_tugas=:nokp and id_tindakan is not null "),['nokp' => $value]);
```

If you want to inject sql query, you have to use DB::raw in laravel

Comment: thank its working. but need to fix the ) should put before is not null") ...thanks a lot ...u save my day ^_^

Comment: @Muthu17 Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51838922/how-can-i-convert-many-statement-mysql-to-laravel-eloquent